# creating advance custom property for a web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property

so far i able to create a custom property with with single control something like this:

```
string _property1; 
public string Property2 
{ 
     get 
     { 
         return _property2; 
     } 
     set 
     { 
         _property2 = value; 
     } 
}
```

but i am looking to have little bit advance something like this:

a textbox with dropdownlist

any idea how would i do that or any link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/

Please see the section on custom web part properties.

Short version:

- Textbox - String/Int
- DropDownList - enum
- Checkbox - bool

Alternatively, if you are looking for more functionality, take a look at [EditorParts](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/08/12/spreading-some-sharepoint-love-to-editorpart.aspx). This link is for 2007, but it should work the same way. Notice that YOU control the markup that is written to the edit mode properties of the web part.

Comment: Tim, i read the blog before i post here, and the blog did not talk about having `dropdownlist with textbox`

Comment: what i am looking is  `TextBox next to it is DropDownList` so for an example, i will have a list of items to select from DDL and textbox to enter the value.

Comment: Gotcha. I think you might be over thinking it then. Why can't you have two separate properties? An enum that defines the DDL values, and the string for the textbox value.

Comment: Abu, I've updated my answer with an alternative approach.